# I want to remove last character from each txt file in a directory using batch script/cmd

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have some `.txt` files for example:

```
a.txt
b.txt
```

Each line of these files contain numbers in the below format:

```
9999999999,  
1111111111,
```

I want to remove `,` after each number by way of a batch script.

The result should be like:

```
9999999999
1111111111
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION 
FOR %%e IN (u:\a.txt u:\b.txt "u:\your files\c one.txt") DO (
 >u:\dummy.tmp (
 FOR /f %%y IN ('TYPE %%e') DO (
  SET "line=%%y"
  ECHO !line:~0,-1!
 )
 )
 MOVE /y u:\dummy.tmp %%e >nul
)

GOTO :EOF
```

Always verify against a test directory before applying to real data.

Filenames are my test files.